# How can I sort this array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I got an array like this.

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => "1039"
    "total" => 2.3
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => "1039"
    "total" => -3.0
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => "10007"
    "total" => 15.5
  ]
]
```

I need "total" for same "id" in the same array.
e.g For "id" = 1039 array should be

```
[2.3, -3.0]
```

For "id" = 10007 array should be

```
[15.5]
```

**My desired array is**

```
[
  [2.3, -3.0],
  [15.5]
]
```

Comment: i think **array_merge_recursive()** will help you out.

Comment: Hey did my answer work for you? If so do not forget to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really want them keyed by the arrays ID.

```
$arr = [ ["id" => "1039", "total" => 2.3],["id" => "1039","total" => -3.0],["id" => "10007","total" => 15.5]];

$total = [];
foreach($arr as $item) {
    $total[$item['id']][] = $item['total'];
}
```

That will return

```
array:2 [
  1039 => array:2 [
    0 => 2.3
    1 => -3.0
  ]
  10007 => array:1 [
    0 => 15.5
  ]
]
```

Comment: That's ok. Is there any way to convert this array to Javascript array ? Like: `[[ 2.3,-3.0],[15.5]]`

Comment: @raaahad yes, `$values = array_values($total);`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over your array and set it to the another array like this:

```
$array = [
    ['id' => 1, 'value' => 2],
    ['id' => 1, 'value' => 3],
    ['id' => 2, 'value' => 5],
];

$temp = [];

foreach($array as $element){
    if(!isset($temp[$element['id']])){
        $temp[$element['id']] = [];
    }
    
    $temp[$element['id']][] = $element['value'];
}


var_dump($temp);
```

Comment: That's ok @gguney. Is there any way to convert this array to Javascript array ? Like: `[[ 2.3,-3.0],[15.5]]`

Comment: If it is ok, please mark it as an answer. You can use json_encode($temp);

Comment: I have tried `json_encode($temp)` but it is giveing me string like `{"1039":[2.3000000000000007,-3],"10007":[15.5]}` .  Should I need to use `implode(":", json_encode($temp))` ?

Comment: Php cant understand json you should send to js to use is as json. Do not forget to mark it as an answer. It is checkmark